# Animation or Transition Properties with Flexbox

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, flexbox

I am trying to get flexbox properties to work with transitions.  Right now, the elements snap into place.  I need them to transition smoothly on hover.  I have tried several things, but nothing seems to work.  I need something that has good cross-browser compatibility and displays well.

Where am I going wrong with this code?

```
HTML
            <!--TOP-->
                <div class="wrap">
                    <section class="secLI">
                        <a href="index.html" class="li4">
                          <h3>Home</h3> 
                        </a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="secLI">
                        <a href="services/services.html" class="li5">
                          <h3>Services</h3>
                        </a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="secLI">
                        <a href="events/events.html" class="li6">
                          <h3>Events</h3>
                        </a>
                    </section>
                  </div>

              <!--BOTTOM-->
                  <div class="wrap">
                      <section class="secLI">
                        <a href="plan/plan.html" class="li4">
                          <h3>Plan an Event</h3> 
                        </a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="secLI">
                        <a href="bands/bands.html" class="li5">
                          <h3>Band Promo</h3>
                        </a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="secLI">
                        <a href="contact/contact.html" class="li6">
                          <h3>Contact</h3>
                        </a>
                    </section>
                  </div>




CSS


.wrap {
            color: #ff7800;
            text-align: center;
            clear: both;
                    /**Background**/
                    background: #366ce8;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            padding-top: 4vh;
            padding: 2.5vh 0 1.5vh;
                    /*Wrap FlexBox Settings*/
                    display: -webkit-box;
                        display: -moz-box;
                        display: -ms-flexbox;
                        display: -webkit-flex;
                        display: -o-flex;
                        display: flex;
                    -webkit-justify-content: center;
                        -moz-justify-content: center;
                        -ms-justify-content: center;
                        -o-justify-content: center;
                        justify-content: center;                        
                    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                        -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
                        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
                        -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
                        flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .wrap section {
          -webkit-flex: 1;
              -moz-flex: 1;
              -ms-flex: 1;
              -o-flex: 1;
              flex: 1;
          cursor: pointer;
          background: #cddc39;
          transition: all .5s;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .wrap section:hover {
          -webkit-flex: 1.5;
              -moz-flex: 1.5;
              -ms-flex: 1.5;
              -o-flex: 1.5;
              flex: 1.5;
          background: #e6ee9c;


          -webkit-animation: -webkit-flex;
            animation: flex;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
                animation-delay: 3s;
          -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-flex;
            -moz-transition-property: -moz-flex;
            -ms-transition-property: -ms-flex;
            -o-transition-property: -o-flex;
            transition-property: flex;
          -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
            -ms-transition-duration: 2s;
            -o-transition-duration: 2s;
            transition-duration: 2s;
          }
```

Comment: Flexbox is a layout mechanism, not a positioning one *per se*. Therefore, transitions do not apply to changing properties of flexbox elements. However, you might want to consider using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for smoothly transitioning layout changes.

Comment: This is an example of something that I found that was close, but it is not quite what I am looking for.  [link](http://codepen.io/DrYSG/pen/ovctn)

Answer (score 1):

Using the same HTML, this is the CSS that I came up with that works.  Note the "!important" value additions.  The code did not work until I added these, even after a hard reload/refresh.

```
CSS

.wrap section:hover {
          background: #e6ee9c;


                  -webkit-animation-name: flexExpand;
                  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
                  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
                  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important; 
                  -moz-animation-name: flexExpand;
                  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
                  -mozt-animation-delay: .2s;
                  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;    
                  -ms-animation-name: flexExpand;
                  -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
                  -ms-animation-delay: .2s;
                  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important; 
                  -o-animation-name: flexExpand;
                  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
                  -o-animation-delay: .2s;
                  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;               
                  animation-name: flexExpand;
                  animation-duration: 1s;
                  animation-delay: .2s;
                  animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
        }

                  @-webkit-keyframes flexExpand {
                      from { -webkit-flex: 1; }
                      to { -webkit-flex: 1.5; }
                      from { flex: 1; }
                      to { flex: 1.5; }
                  }                   
                  @-moz-keyframes flexExpand {
                      from { -webkit-flex: 1; }
                      to { -webkit-flex: 1.5; }
                      from { flex: 1; }
                      to { flex: 1.5; }
                  }
                  @-ms-keyframes flexExpand {
                      from { -webkit-flex: 1; }
                      to { -webkit-flex: 1.5; }
                      from { flex: 1; }
                      to { flex: 1.5; }
                  }
                  @-o-keyframes flexExpand {
                      from { -webkit-flex: 1; }
                      to { -webkit-flex: 1.5; }
                      from { flex: 1; }
                      to { flex: 1.5; }
                  }
                  @keyframes flexExpand {
                      from { -webkit-flex: 1; }
                      to { -webkit-flex: 1.5; }
                      from { flex: 1; }
                      to { flex: 1.5; }
                  }
```